# How to retrieve the GlobalId from a selected object on an IFC file?

Tags: scripting, export, select

I am trying to start a script to export attributes from selected objects from an IFC file in BlenderBIM, but I am getting an error "'Object' has no attribute 'id'". This is the code so far:

```
import bpy 
import csv
import ifcopenshell
from blenderbim.bim.ifc import IfcStore

ifc = ifcopenshell.open(IfcStore.path)
csv_file_path = "C:/Users/nameless/file.csv"
active_object = bpy.context.active_object
element_global_id = active_object.id()
print(element_global_id)
```

Am I getting the selected object wrong? Is this method a good method to get many objects at once?

Comment: `bpy.types.Object` don't have `id` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [BlenderBIM Addon](https://blenderbim.org/) is a third party addon and the developers and community are most active on other platforms. You will find most exchanges happening in the [OsArch.org](https://community.osarch.org/) forum and [Chat](https://osarch.org/chat/). For pure development questions and posting bug reports, please refer to https://github.com/IfcOpenShell/IfcOpenShell. Full disclosure, I am active in both.

That being said, I think this is a valid question. The [IFC file format](https://www.buildingsmart.org/standards/bsi-standards/industry-foundation-classes/) is quite complicated and the BlenderBIM Addon uses several layers of abstraction to be able to manipulate the data without having to know all the in and outs of the format as a prerequisite. For simple querying you might want to explore https://github.com/IfcOpenShell/IfcOpenShell/blob/v0.7.0/src/blenderbim/blenderbim/tool/ifc.py.

So your script can be condensed to

```
import bpy 
import blenderbim.tool as tool

ifc = tool.Ifc.get()  # Get the active file, no need to query the path from disk
active_object = bpy.context.active_object
ifc_element = tool.Ifc.get_entity(active_object)
print([attr for attr in dir(ifc_element) if not attr.startswith("_")])  # Print all available attributes
print(ifc_element.GlobalId)
```

Comment: Thanks Gorgious, I will follow your recommendations about OsArch.org and interact there.

The code worked fine, I will try to evolve from that, many thanks for you help :)